# Angular 2: combine bar chart and line chart

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I wan to combine bar and line chart in dashboard in angular 2 in my custom component following this github link:

https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin

(The dashboard has an in built bar chart and i m trying to call it in my custom component )

I created a component called barChart.component.ts

**UPDATED CODE**

**var/www/html/Angular2\ng2-admin-master\src\app\pages\dashboard\barChart\barChart.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

import { ChartistJsService } from '../../charts/components/chartistJs/chartistJs.service';
import * as Chart from 'chart.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'bar-chart',
  template: `
         <ba-chartist-chart baChartistChartClass="ct-chart"
                        baChartistChartType="Bar"
                         [baChartistChartData]="data['simpleBarData']"  
                       [baChartistChartOptions]="data['simpleBarOptions']">
          </ba-chartist-chart>
         <ba-chartist-chart baChartistChartClass="ct-chart"
                       baChartistChartType="Line"
                       [baChartistChartData]="data['simpleLineData']"
                       [baChartistChartOptions]="data['simpleLineOptions']">
         </ba-chartist-chart>
       `
})

// TODO: move chart.js to it's own component
export class BarChart {
     public simpleBarData: {
      data:any;
      constructor(private _chartistJsService:ChartistJsService) {
   }

   ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this._chartistJsService.getAll();
    }
}
```

Here both bar and line chart displays (line chart below bar chart alone with axis), but i want only the line chart to me merged over bar chart(without x and y axis of line chart).

Comment: There is no `data` variable in your class, therefore the property simpleBarData cannot be read of something that doesn't exist. Initialize your variables properly, then pass the correct variables to your child component.

Comment: Ok updated the code, got the chart now, thanks TommyF!!

Comment: Could you suggest me on how to merge line chart over bar chart for the above updated code!